# Cosine proof of vectors

Tags: calculus

Hi this is the excerpt from the book I'm reading

> *Proof:* We will prove the theorem for vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ (the proof for $\Bbb R^2$ is similar). Let ${\bf v}=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and ${\bf w}=(w_1,w_2,w_3).$ By the law of cosines we have $$\|{\bf v}-{\bf w} \|^2=\|{\bf v}\|^2+\|{\bf w}\|^2-2\|{\bf v}\|\|{\bf w}\|\cos\theta\tag{1.9}$$
>   (note that equation (1.9) holds even for the "degenerate" cases $\theta=0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$).

[image: illustration]

Problem is I see $\|\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{w}\|^2  =  \mathbf{w}^2  -  \mathbf{v}^2$.

and I don't know how the book  worked to theorem 1.9 in the example

Any help?

Comment: they've used the law of cosines on the triangle in the diagram. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

Comment: Seems to me it's a proof in $\Bbb R^2$, since ordinarily trig is planar :D

Comment: "Problem is I see $||\mathbf v - \mathbf w||^2 = \mathbf w^2 - \mathbf v^2$."  Huh?  First, it doesn't make sense to square a vector using vector algebra.  Second, why did you come to this erroneous conclusion?  Can you explain your reasoning, so it can be corrected?

Comment: I was looking at is as a triangle in 2-D. Although I do realize now the book simply stated the law of cosines, did manipulation on said law, to arrive at a theorem without actually proving or even introducing the law ... which made difficult following its line of reasoning.

Comment: @user155679 , it seems u're really interested in vectors ;)
Good luck boy

Answer (score 1):

Whether in 2D or 3D, if you say
$$\|\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{w}\|^2  =  \mathbf{w}^2  -  \mathbf{v}^2$$

then
$$\|\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{w}\|^2  +  \mathbf{v}^2  =  \mathbf{w}^2$$

This means that $\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{w}$,  $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ satisfy the Pythagoras theorem with $\mathbf{w}$ as hypotenuse, and $\mathbf{v}$ & $\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{w}$ as the two sides.

As Pythagoras theorem is applicable to right angle triangles, therefore the angle opposite to $\mathbf{w}$ in your diagram would be $90^o$.

Now this may not always be the case. Thus more generally we use the law of cosines.